# The June 23 issue of New Scientist says gravitational waves twist when they travel, and do so counterclockwise. Why?

Tags: gravitational-waves, polarization

Also, the same article then says that if gravitational waves ever did move in a clockwise fashion, it means the black holes slammed into each other much more rapidly.

Huh?

Comment: What does it even mean, clockwise? They exist in 3D space...

Comment: trying to describe in words this type of behavior https://youtu.be/Y6tSFk5ESAo

Comment: Link to article?

Comment: This is popularisation  of physics, not physics itself.

Comment: The article is a Feature article in the June 23-29 New Scientist.  By Daniel Cossins, called 'The space-time echoes that point to a new theory of reality.'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question your question was very interesting. At first,gravitational waves twists both clockwise and counterclockwise because of the polarization. The gravitational waves scatter and ripple from both left pole and right pole so those waves can scatter and ripple again from that point.

Although,I do not know why the black holes slammed into each other much more rapidly.

last access 9 Jul 2018
references:

・http://www.caltech.edu/news/bicep2-discovers-first-direct-evidence-inflation-and-primordial-gravitational-waves-42305

・http://www.scpr.org/programs/airtalk/2014/03/18/36544/scientists-discover-a-smoking-gun-in-the-big-bang/

・https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0311070

Comment: Can you add a basic summary of those articles or some important quotation from them? It'd be useful in case the links rot.

Comment: please note that more recent publications have reduced the signal to not significant due  to noise from interactions in space.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00612

Comment: First of all, I corrected the date.  It's the June 23-29 issue of New Scientist, not March.          In the article, according to general relativity, gravitational waves 'do not preferentially corkscrew in any particular direction along their direction of travel.'  But Nicholas Yunes of Montana State University has added a new theoretical 'field' with modifications that 'imply that gravitational waves would be more likely to corkscrew clockwise or anticlockwise, depending on the direction in which the binary black holes orbit one another and the relative location of the observer.'

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the article [here online, page 35.](https://app.box.com/s/updgm72ga2ujxdzf3ed5msj50c6komqp)

It is a special proposed modified theory for gravity that gives this prediction:

> Yunes, for his part, is partial to a theory 
>   that conjures an extra field into existence. 
>   It couples to gravity in such a way that it would 
>   explain why matter was not annihilated by 
>   antimatter in the first moments of universe – 
>   and thus why the universe isn’t filled with 
>   radiation alone. Such modifications imply 
>   that gravitational waves would be more
>   likely to corkscrew clockwise rather than 
>   anticlockwise. That would, in turn, mean we 
>   would observe black holes spiralling into
>   one another much faster and more violently 
>   than relativity predicts.

Note that this proposed model aims to explain why our universe is mainly made of particles, and to do that introduces an asymmetry that has also an effect on the polarization of gravity waves.

The [existing LIGO data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09505.pdf) are being examined for polarization but the errors are such that no conclusion can be drawn at present. Analysis tools  are set in place so that eventually one might check up such a modified gravity theory prediction in the future experiments, as a number of options are discussed in the conclusions.

At the moment in the [LIGO data](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v3) there is no indication of a bias in clockwise or anticlockwise polarization of the gravitational waves, as [visualized here.](https://youtu.be/Y6tSFk5ESAo)

If such an asymmetry is ever detected in black hole mergers, it would be a good validation for a model which by this observation  will also  explain the observed baryon antibaryon asymmetry.